# Extracting raster using shapefile to another raster

Tags: raster, r, extract

I have a raster (say r) and a polygon shapefile (say s, containing many polygons). I want to convert the pixelated r to mean of s boundaries. And I need these boundary means as another raster file.

What I have now is the extract function:

```
rmean <- extract(r,s,fun=mean,df=TRUE)
```

but, I am not able to convert this into a raster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign the values to the polygons and then rasterise the polygons on that value.

Using `polys` and `r` from `example(extract)`:

```
> polys$r = extract(r, polys, fun=mean)
> rp = rasterize(polys, r, "r")
> plot(rp)
```

[image]